# Unittesting paramiko ssh connections

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko, python-unittest

I want to do a simple test of an ssh connection function like this:

```
def ssh_connect(host, key, user):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(StringIO.StringIO(key), password='passkey')
    ssh.connect(host, username=user, pkey=k)
    return ssh
```

I don't want to have to pass a legit server, username and key.  Assuming the test was done on a linux server would you ssh to yourself in the test scenario?

Comment: If you are unittesting it, maybe consider using mocks? It will not test connection, but your code logic. 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: have a look at [Mock a Remote Host in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917649/mock-a-remote-host-in-python)